# Merge 2 subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I have 2 subqueries with the same columns from two different tables that i want to turn in to a view with the rows from both the subqueries.

```
(SELECT one AS a, two AS b FROM table_a WHERE condition_a=true) 
(SELECT tree AS a, four AS b FROM table_b WHERE condition_b=true) 

( For the example lets assume that all data is VARCHAR(10) )
```

From those 2 queries i want to make a view with the columns "a" and "b", with all the results from both queries.

Is this possible? and if it is how can i do that?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `union all`:

```
create view v_ab as
    SELECT one AS a, two AS b FROM table_a WHERE condition_a=true
    union all
    SELECT tree AS a, four AS b FROM table_b WHERE condition_b=true;
```